# How do I display a snackbar over/on top of the soft keyboard. Upon clicking the button, success() and error() displays behind the keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

Here is my code for clicking the submitButton

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            //when submit is clicked go through verification
            //verification would include
            //displaying a toast error message
            //if pin input is shorter than requiredLength
//            validate()


            //same idea as above but this time using a snackbar in place of toast
            verify()


        }
```

This is my verify method with a closeKeyboard method that I dislike using. I would rather have the snackbar display over the keyboard - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eifc44nH1xE. However, I would like to close the keyboard when clicking out of the view  for ex... after you typed in digits and click on blank screen(the parent)

```
 private fun verify() {
            val requiredLength = 4
            val editTextView: EditText = findViewById(R.id.pinInput)
            val textLength = editTextView.text.length
    
            if (textLength != requiredLength) {
                error()
            } else {
                success()
            }
            closeKeyboard()
    
        }
```

This is my snackbar success method. I have another one for error(looks identical)

```
 private fun success() {
            val view = findViewById<View>(R.id.root_layout)
            val snackTime = Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
            val snacking = getString(R.string.success_message)
            val snackbarsuccess = Snackbar.make(view, snacking, snackTime)
            snackbarsuccess.show()
            snackbarsuccess.setAction("Close", View.OnClickListener { snackbarsuccess.dismiss() })
            snackbarsuccess.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.teal_200))
    
            val text =
                snackbarsuccess.view.findViewById((com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)) as TextView
            text.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white))
    
    
        }
```

I found this code and pasted it. The problem with this code is that it closes the keyboard and you would then have to click back into the edit text view to display the keyboard. I don't like this. I hope that makes sense. When I am clicking out to the side, it switches the keyboard to a different style. I don't like this.

```
 private fun closeKeyboard() {
        val view: View = this.currentFocus!!
        if (view != null) {
            val imm: InputMethodManager =
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` to your activity tag in the manifest.

Comment: Nice! It worked  beautifully. I have tried this before, but made the mistake of putting it inside of the application tag. I appreciate you Dan.

Comment: Of course, glad you were able to get what you needed.